# Swagger page is blank

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration, swagger, swagger-ui

I am running [this](https://github.com/papakonstantinouko/Catstagram) .net core 3.1 api project and i got swashbuckle installed and configured swagger on the startup. However when i navigate to http://localhost:5000/swagger/index.html the page is totally empty. Can someone advise how to properly configure the project?